# Linear Second order ODE with oscillating solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered the following second-order ODE while tutoring recently, and struggled with the proper approach:

$x^2y''+2xy'+\alpha y = 0$

The problem is: for which values of $\alpha$ do solutions oscillate as $x\to \infty$?

Eventually, we gave up and asked Wolfram Alpha for a solution. Based on what we saw there, we were able to reverse engineer a method for solving it: assume that $y(x)=x^r$, plug this assumption into the original equation, and solve for $r$. It turns out there is a $\sqrt{1-4\alpha}$ term in the resulting solution ($r=\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\alpha})$), so you get osciallating solutions if $\alpha>\frac14$. Super.

My question is this: what kind of intuition should guide one's approach to this problem? How might I have known which form of solution to look for? What is the usual approach for a problem like this? There's kind of a nice symmetry to the original equation - how can I use that to guide me towards a solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: this is an equation of type Emden Fowler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that with $y=x^r$, when apply the derivative operator $k$ times and then multiply by $x^k$, you keep the same power. So there are chances to find a solution this way.

Alternatively, you can try with the change of variables $t = \log x$ to get back to constant coefficients.

Comment: I'm trying to do that substitution, but I'm having a hard time replacing everything in $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}+\alpha y$. In particular, how do I rewrite $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in terms of $y$ and $t$ only?

Comment: **Hint:** using this change of variables, $x df/dx = df/dt$.